# ./hello.sh: line 3: [10: command not found

Tags: bash

I was trying to learn `if statement` in bash and its showing the error command not found

```
#! /bin/bash
  count=10  
  if [$count -eq 10 ]  
  then  
 echo "true"  
fi
```

Comment: You need a space between [ and $ in `if [$count -eq 10 ] ` so it should be `if [ $count -eq 10 ] ` !

Comment: Note, I removed the version tag as it is not relevant here and for that the question will not be closed due to 12.04 being EOL. You should consider an update tto a supported version of Ubuntu anyways ...

Answer (score 5):

`[` is not part of the if/else syntax, but a command itself. The `if` simply checks if the return value of the command it calls is `0`.

So, you have to separate the arguments of the `[` command from the command name with a space:

```
if [ $count -eq 10 ]; ...
```

You can check the return of just any command, e.g. `if grep pattern file; then ... fi`.

Other similar commands are

`[[`, `test` or `((`.

See [this](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest) for more details.

Comment: Good explanation of `[` and in this case it's enough to not confuse the readers, so +1 for good answer and clarity. But it is worth mentioning couple points. One, `[` and `test` are the same command, so `if test $count -eq 10` is equivalent. Another, that `[` nowadays is a built-in command in many shells, but there's also external `/usr/bin/[` and `/usr/bin/test` for historic reasons and compatibility with standards. Arithmetic Evaluation `((` is a command, while Arithmetic Expansion `$(` is not a command, it's rather a form of word expansion and works mostly for assignments.